# find list of tables, packages , procedures which are locked and having compile issue

Tags: database, oracle, database-schema

We were working in one of the migration project , migrating database from one database server to other database server. We want to check whether all the tables , procedures , packages are migrated properly with all the required permissions.

While accessing the database we are facing issues with access lock, permissions ..... etc..

Is there any way we can verify all the objects and its related issue between two databases.

Pls let me know if my question is repeated or need to be more elaborated..

Comment: What do you consider as "check whether all ... are migrated properly"?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit.. Thanks a lot for the reply. Actually when we observe few of the tables are not migrated properly. We want to check whether all the objects like tables , procedure packages and others are completely migrated and provided permissions as is..

Comment: Still too vague.  What do you mean by "not migrated properly"?  Object is not in the new database at all?  It is there but with an object status of INVALID (whereas it is VALID in the  pre-migration)?  Something else?  Exactly HOW did you perform the migration? What error messages are you seeing, and what activity generates them?

Comment: It sounds like you want to **compare schemas** between your source database and target database, to make sure they're identical. There are tools for this - TOAD and SQL Developer both have "schema compare" tools, and there are other packages and scripts available. http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_compare_schemas.htm

Comment: For plain validity status you would normally recompile the schema and check `user_`/`dba_objects.status` for anything that wasn't 'VALID'. However if you are looking at OS-related things like ACLs for email, that could be trickier.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT owner || '.' || object_name "Object",
       os_user_name "Terminal",
       oracle_username "User_code",
       NVL (lockwait, 'ACTIVE') "Wait",
       DECODE (locked_mode,
          2, 'ROW SHARE',
          3, 'ROW EXCLUSIVE',
          4, 'SHARE',
          5, 'SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE',
          6, 'EXCLUSIVE',
          'UNKNOWN')
          "Lockmode",
       object_type,
       session_id,
       serial# "Serial",
       c.SID,
       c.username,
       c.osuser,
       c.machine,
       c.inst_id "Instance"
FROM sys.gv_$locked_object A, sys.all_objects b, sys.gv_$session c
WHERE     A.object_id = b.object_id
      AND c.SID = A.session_id
      AND (c.ownerid = 2147483644)
      AND c.inst_id = A.inst_id
      AND UPPER (c.username) LIKE DECODE (:FILTER, 'Oracle User', :VALUE, '%')
      AND UPPER (c.osuser) LIKE DECODE (:FILTER, 'OS User', :VALUE, '%')
      AND UPPER (c.machine) LIKE DECODE (:FILTER, 'Machine', :VALUE, '%')
```

feel free to skip the filters